# Este código convierte sin problemas de decimal a binario. Pero al tratar de convertir binario a decimal no imprime nada. Que esta pasando realmente?

Tags: javascript

Estoy tratando de escribir una función para completar un ejercicio. La función debe convertir un número decimal a binario y viceversa. La función recibe dos argumentos, en primera instancia el número, ya sea binario/decimal. Lo que le dice a la función que conversión debe realizar es el segundo parámetro (base), cuándo paso por ejemplo, binarioDecimal(5, 2); // imprime 101, eso me dice que con la conversación decimal/binario no hay ningún problema. El problema esta en cuando trato de convertir binario a decimal, y paso los argumentos a la función no imprime nada, donde esta el error?

```
const binarioDecimal = (number = 0, base = 0) => { // 0 por default si el usuario no pasa ningun valor
  if (number === 0 || base === 0) {
    console.log(0);
  } else if (typeof number === "number" && typeof base === "number") {
    if (base === 2) {
      let num = number;
      let binary = (num % 2).toString();

      for (; num > 1; ) {
        num = parseInt(num / 2);
        binary = (num % 2) + binary;
      }
      console.log(binary);
    }
  } else if (typeof number === "number" && typeof base === "number") {
    // aquí es donde creo que la función falla
    if (base === 10) {
      var decimal = 0,
        i = 0,
        resto;
      while (number !== 0) {
        resto = number % 10;
        number = Number.parseInt(number / 10);
        decimal = decimal + resto * Math.pow(2, i);
        ++i;
      }
      console.log(decimal);
    }
  }
};
binarioDecimal(); // 0
binarioDecimal(23, 2); // 10111
binarioDecimal(101, 10); // nada :(
```

Comment: dentro de la funcion en el segundo else if tenes dos condiciones unidas por un && pero ambas condiciones son exactamente iguales. No se si ese es el problema pero eso noto.

Comment: No, no es eso. Cambie el pequeño error del else if pero aun así, la función no devuelve un resultado.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

¿Qué sucede si divide los checks en dos condiciones separadas?

```
const binarioDecimal = (number = 0, base = 0) => { 

  if (number === 0 || base === 0) {
    console.log(0);
  } 

  if (base === 2) {
    var num = number;
    var binary = (num % 2).toString();

    for (; num > 1; ) {
      num = parseInt(num / 2);
      binary = (num % 2) + binary; 
    }
    console.log(binary); 
  }

  if (base === 10) {
    var decimal = 0,
        i = 0,
        resto;
    while (number !== 0) {
      resto = number % 10;
      number = Number.parseInt(number / 10);
      decimal = decimal + resto * Math.pow(2, i);
      ++i;
    }
    console.log(decimal); 
  }
}
binarioDecimal(); // 0
binarioDecimal(23, 2); // 10111
binarioDecimal(101, 10); // 5
```

Comment: Me resulto útil tu recomendación gracias. :)

Answer (score 0):

//Está mal configurado el primer bucle if. El segundo parámetro (base) debe //ir anidado dentro del primer if:

```
const binarioDecimal = (number = 0, base = 0) => { // 0 por default si el usuario no pasa ningun valor
  if (number === 0 || base === 0) {
    console.log(0);
  } else if (typeof number === "number" && typeof base === "number") {
    if (base === 2) {
      let num = number;
      let binary = (num % 2).toString();

      for (; num > 1; ) {
        num = parseInt(num / 2);
        binary = (num % 2) + binary;
      }
      console.log(binary);
    }else if (base === 10) {
      var decimal = 0,
        i = 0,
        resto;
      while (number !== 0) {
        resto = number % 10;
        number = Number.parseInt(number / 10);
        decimal = decimal + resto * Math.pow(2, i);
        ++i;
      }
      console.log(decimal);
    }
  } 
    
    
  }
};
binarioDecimal(); // 0
binarioDecimal(23, 2); // 10111
binarioDecimal(101, 10); // nada :(
```